# Add watermark to existing PDF using adobe acrobat pro from windows batch

Tags: adobe, acrobat

I don't normally script in Adobe and the rabbit hole is very deep after doing some searching, so I was wondering if someone knows how I can add a watermark to an existing PDF by calling Adobe Acrobat Pro from a windows batch file.  I already know about 'Actions" in Adobe as well as Javascript, but not sure how I could call one of these from a batch file.  I'm open to suggestions/ideas here though if it achieves the same thing and is fairly straight forward -- even if not using Adobe.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you exactly want but here a short vbs example, which can easy changed to a windows batch file. Good luck, Reinhard

```
file = "d:\Test.pdf"

'// open acrobat and set required objects
Set App = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
app.show
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
Set AForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App") 'from AFormAPI

'// open the file and add a watermark based on text (using AcroJs)
If AVDoc.Open(file,"") Then
   AForm.Fields.ExecuteThisJavaScript "this.addWatermarkFromText(""Confidential"", 0, font.Helv, 24, color.red);"
end if

Set AVDoc = Nothing
Set AForm = Nothing
Set APP = Nothing
```

Comment: cool this may be what i was looking for (I was having trouble to find the extension method to execute the java script from VB.net).  I also found an extension to the GPDDoc.GetJSObject called AddWatermarkFromText that i'll try.